# Angular 2 Unit Testing: Injecting Typemoq objects

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, mocking, jasmine

I'm implementing a unit test for a Service in Angular 2 (RC4) in Typescript. The service to test ("Calculation") uses a lot of other components ("Bausparen"), which on their part use components ("BausparenInput"). All components are declared @Injectable().

I tried to mock the depending components like Bausparen using [Typemoq](https://github.com/florinn/typemoq) and injecting them before running the tests. Anyway, it doesn't work:

```
FAILED TESTS:
Calculation Service
× should return empty array when fromYear > toYear
  PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)
factory
factory
resolveReflectiveFactory
resolveReflectiveProvider
map@[native code]
apply@[native code]
call@[native code]
call@[native code]
Call
map
resolveReflectiveProviders
resolve
resolveAndCreateChild
createInjector
execute
```

Inside [Jasmines](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) describe function, the code looks like this:

```
let calcInput = x => x.calc(TypeMoq.It.isAnyNumber(), TypeMoq.It.isAnyNumber());
let calcInputFormer = x => x.calc(TypeMoq.It.isAnyNumber(), TypeMoq.It.isAnyNumber(), TypeMoq.It.isAnyNumber());
let calcOutput = (y, m) => new CalcOutput();
let calcOutputFormer = (y, m, f) => new CalcOutput();
let bausparenMock = TypeMoq.Mock.ofType(Bausparen);
bausparenMock.setup(calcInput).returns(calcOutput);
bausparenMock.setup(calcInputFormer).returns(calcOutputFormer);

beforeEach(() => {
  addProviders([CalculationService,
    { provide: Bausparen, useClass: bausparenMock }]);
});

it('should return empty array when fromYear > toYear',
  inject([CalculationService], (calculation: CalculationService) => {
    let result = calculation.getValues(6, 2017, 6, 2016);
    expect(result.length).toBe(0);
}));
```

and signature of the class to mock is this:

```
class Bausparen implements Calculation {
  calc(year: number, month: number, formerAmount?: number): CalcOutput {...}
}
```

The error message doesn't really tell me anything. I don't even get if it's a problem in the setup of my mock or in injecting it. Has anybody had a similar error before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace:

```
{ provide: Bausparen, useClass: bausparenMock }
```

with:

```
{ provide: Bausparen, useValue: bausparenMock }
```

Because mock is value not a class

Also look at [ts-mockito](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito)